# Can I see who blocked me on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

How can I find out who blocked me on Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to tell if someone has blocked you; however, there are third party applications that can tell you when someone has unfollowed you (which happens automatically when you are blocked), such as [Unfollowgram](http://unfollowgram.com).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My concern is about the users who don't follow me. When they block me, Unfollowgram cannot help me since they don't follow me already. Do you know any 3rd party apps that can achieve what I ask for?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Followers app from the app store.